# Python3, can't seem to grasp how I can take information from a single file and distribute it among several others

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a task where I have to gather alot of information which exist on a txt file and sort them. The info is around personal information and comes in order. Such as
Last Name First Name
Social Security Number

### Adress

And so on

My goal is to first sort the information out so I can print them out in that order, and then decide the sex of the fictional character information that is given.

I thought about taking in the information in the file and sorting it to

- one list with only names
- one list with only social security number
- one list with only adresses

then use some sort of zip function to add the indexes over the lists together in order to create a profile. In this way I would be able to look at the social securtitynumber and display the sex of the person.

The code I have come up with sofar is

```
with open ("names.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8" ) as allasinfo:
namn = []
personnummer = []
adress = []
for x in allasinfo.readlines():
    i = 3
    while i > 0:


        namn.append(x)
        i-=1

        personnummer.append(x)
        i-=1

        adress.append(x)
        i-=1
```

My plan here was that the program would move the first index in the file into the first list of names and the second row would be the social security and so on.. The program prints out all the information in all 3 lists, making them identical. Is there any way to split information from a file into 3 different locations the way that I am trying?

Comment: What do you mean by "decide the sex of the fictional character information that is given."? How is that done?

Comment: In Sweden we have a 10 digit social security number, basically our birthdate + some more and the digit that's 2th from the right side, second last is either even or odd depending on the sex (gender) 
Gender was the word I was looking for before, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach a problem like this.  It sounds like your text file contains raw data like:

```
Name One
1111111
111 One Street
Name Two
2222222
222 Two Street
Name Three
3333333
333 Three Street
```

If that's the case, what you want to do is track the line number as you read the data, then assign each line to a value based off that line number.  Rather than store the resulting data in different arrays, I tend to find it easier to store it an array of dictionary elements, so you can treat each unit of data as one set, it makes processing the data down the line more straight forward, and means you don't need to pass around multiple arrays to different helper functions.

```py
values = []

with open("names.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as allasinfo:
    line_number = 0
    # The target keys in each dictionary object we'll create
    target_keys = ['name', 'number', 'address']
    # Just use the file object's built in enumerator
    for x in allasinfo:
        # if this line number starts a new record set, add
        # a dictionary to the list of values
        if line_number % len(target_keys) == 0:
            values.append({})
        # And add this row to the last dictionary, using the line
        # number to note which key type this is
        values[-1][target_keys[line_number % len(target_keys)]] = x
        # Increment the line number
        line_number += 1
```

This will store the values in an array called `values`, each with three entries.  If your text file doesn't contain enough lines, the final element will miss some entries, so make sure to handle that case.